# UITable view,images,rssfeeds

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

how to add an image on the table view header....where the image is read from rss feed and stored in the array called item below is the code

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
   {
    return 69.0;
   }

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
     {

  UIView* headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 69.0)];
   headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"1" ofType: @"jpg"]]];
    return headerView;
}


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{            
    //NSLog(@"found this element: %@", elementName);
    currentElement = [elementName copy];
    currentElement1=[attributeDict copy];
    item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
        // clear out our story item caches...
        currentTitle = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        currentDate = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        currentSummary = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        currentLink = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        currentString=[[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        currentImage = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        currentContent=[[NSMutableString alloc]init];   
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"enclosure"]) 
    {
        currentString=[attributeDict objectForKey:@"url"];
        //  NSLog(@"what is my current string:%@",currentString);
        [item setObject:currentString forKey:@"url"];


    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"itunes:image"])

        {
        currentImage = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"href"];
        [item setObject:currentImage forKey:@"href"];
       // NSLog(@"the item current string:%@",item);

            NSString *imagefile1 = [item objectForKey:@"href"]; 
            NSString *escapedURL=[imagefile1 stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
            UIImage *image1 = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:escapedURL]]];
            NSLog(@"here we go dis is awesome:%@",image1);
            //cell.imageView.image=image1;
            image.image=image1;

            }

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{     
    //NSLog(@"ended element: %@", elementName);
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
        [item setObject:currentTitle forKey:@"title"];
        [item setObject:currentLink forKey:@"link"];
        [item setObject:currentSummary forKey:@"description"];
        [item setObject:currentContent forKey:@"content:encoded"];
        [item setObject:currentDate forKey:@"pubDate"];
        [stories addObject:[item copy]];

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- parse XML
- Download Image to disk
- load Image into ImageView
- add imageView to headerView

Each of this step is well documented on SO, [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com) and elsewhere.